# Equal width sidebar columns with CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Is it possible to have both left and right columns have the same width while the middle column takes the remaining space? I don't want to set percentages like `grid-template-columns: 20% 60% 20%`, because it's not always certain what the content of these columns will be.

Flexbox and tables doesn't seem to have solutions for this problem so I tried again with Grid fractions but without any luck.

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.col-1 {
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.col-2 {
    background-color: #CCFFCC;
}

.col-3 {
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col col-1">This is column one</div>
    <div class="col col-2">Morbi semper accumsan odio, a interdum nisl dapibus eget. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque placerat urna ut finibus mollis. Morbi risus odio, pulvinar non rutrum nec, lacinia sit amet diam. Sed vitae imperdiet felis, sed gravida tortor. Maecenas a nisl ac leo finibus sollicitudin. Vestibulum non scelerisque odio, vehicula aliquam tortor.</div>
    <div class="col col-3">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1ghv95n7/) using flexbox ? if you want both columns to be the same width this means applying a fixed width or use percentage, also what happens if the width is smaller than the content ?

Comment: I tried the method you suggested but the columns should be as wide as their content. They shouldn't be smaller.

Comment: *columns should be as wide as their content* If one column's content is smaller than the other column's content then they can't be equal size, I suggest that you edit your question and add all the rules you want.

Comment: There are no more rules, it's all in here: "...both left and right columns have the same width while the middle column takes the remaining space".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *hacky* idea where the trick is to have a grid with two columns and taking half the width of container. Then you make both left and right column above each other to make sure they are equal and you do some magic with translation to rectify the overlap and get what you want.

The only drawback is that we need to know the width of the main container.

Check the below on full screen for perfect result since I am using `100vw` that includes the width of the scroll.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width:50%;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(0,1fr);
  margin:10px 0;
}

.col-1,
.col-3{
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
  white-space: nowrap;
  grid-column:1;
  grid-row:1;
}

.col-2 {
  background-color: #CCFFCC;
  width:200%;
}

.col-3 {
  background-color: #CCCCFF;
  transform:translateX(calc(100vw - 100%));
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col col-1">This is column one</div>
  <div class="col col-2">Morbi semper accumsan odio, a interdum nisl dapibus eget. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis </div>
  <div class="col col-3">Column 3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="col col-1">This is column one</div>
  <div class="col col-2">Morbi semper </div>
  <div class="col col-3">Column 3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="col col-1">This is column one too long</div>
  <div class="col col-2">Morbi semper </div>
  <div class="col col-3">Column 3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="col col-1">This is column one too long</div>
  <div class="col col-2">Morbi semper accumsan odio, a interdum nisl dapibus eget. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis </div>
  <div class="col col-3">Column 3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="col col-1">..</div>
  <div class="col col-2">Morbi semper accumsan odio, a interdum nisl dapibus eget. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis </div>
  <div class="col col-3">Column 3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="col col-1">..</div>
  <div class="col col-2">Morbi  </div>
  <div class="col col-3">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Here is a step by step illustration to understand the trick:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width:50%;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(0,1fr);
  margin:10px 0;
}

.col-1,
.col-3{
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
  white-space: nowrap;
  grid-column:1;
  grid-row:1;
}

.col-2 {
  background-color: #CCFFCC;
}

.col-3 {
  background-color: #CCCCFF;
  opacity:0.8;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col col-1">This is column one</div>
  <div class="col col-2">Morbi semper accumsan odio, a interdum nisl</div>
  <div class="col col-3">Column 3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="col col-1">This is column one</div>
  <div class="col col-2" >Morbi semper accumsan odio, a interdum nisl </div>
  <div class="col col-3" style="transform:translateX(calc(100vw - 100%));">Column 3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="col col-1">This is column one</div>
  <div class="col col-2" style="width:200%;">Morbi semper accumsan odio, a interdum nisls </div>
  <div class="col col-3" style="transform:translateX(calc(100vw - 100%));">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the idea, but this will not be applicable because I can't know for sure which column will determine the max width. It can be either the left or right one.

Comment: @KeesHak it's not an issue, the code will always make both equal width then it's up to you to decide which one will fix the width. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/c938hfsk/ .. I made the right column defining the width even if the left one has more content